# How to pass report parameter to data source url

Tags: birt, url-encoding

under my property binding I have this:

```
 <expression name="value" type="javascript">"http://localhost:8080/myapp/report/fetch?param1 = "+params["param1"];</expression>
```

but when I run my app I am getting this error:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/myapp/report/fetch%3Fparam1%20=%20value1
```

as you can see the **?** mark in the *url* is encoded into **%3** , any way to handle this?

Comment: What type of datasource is it? Seems to be XML but could you confirm.

Comment: yes, it is xml data source

Comment: The same is working for me: i defined an XML datasource on a web service, and added a question mark with a report parameter value in property bindings: the datasource is correctly accessed in the report. Therefore it seems to be a trouble with the servlet serving your XML data. When you edit this datasource in BIRT Eclipse designer, and click "Test connection" with URL *http://localhost:8080/myapp/report/fetch?param1=value1* does it work? Could you post the full stacktrace of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the spaces in your URL infront of and after the `=`. They are not getting removed and are not allowed at this place in the URL. The encoding of `?` to `%3F` is fine as you can see from the [HTML URL encoding table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

Change:

```
<expression name="value" type="javascript">"http://localhost:8080/myapp/report/fetch?param1 = "+params["param1"];</expression>
```

to:

```
<expression name="value" type="javascript">"http://localhost:8080/myapp/report/fetch?param1="+params["param1"];</expression>
```